# c++ ifstream to stringstream using getline()

Tags: c++

I am making a bowling program for school that stored scores in a text file with the format:

```
paul 10 9 1 8 1, ...etc
jerry 8 1 8 1 10 ...etc
...etc
```

I want to read the file into a `stringstream` using `getline()` so I can use each `endl` as a marker for a new player's score (because the amount of numbers on a line can be variable, if you get a spare or strike on round 10). I can then read the `stringstream` using `>>` to get each score and push it into a `vector` individually.

However, when trying to use `getline(fstream, stringstream)`, I get an error

> no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::fstream, std::stringstream)

How can I make this work?

My code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

//other parts of the program which probably don't matter for this error

vector <int> gameScore;
vector<string> playerName;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
string name;
int score;
stringstream line;

while (in.good()){ //in is my fstream
    playerName.push_back(name);
    cout << playerName[i] << " ";
    i++;
    getline(in, line);

    while (line >> score){
        gameScore.push_back(score);
        cout << gameScore[j] << " ";
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `fstream` and `stringstream` should function the same for your use case here. You can use `>>` with the `fstream`. Is there any reason you want this in a `stringstream`?

Comment: I need to getline() so i grab all the scores up to the endl (because the ammount of numbers on a line is variable) then read each individual score and push it into the vector until the stringstream is empty (the filestream won't be empty yet because there can be more lines of scores) IF I just getline() the fstream then I will have no way to separate each score individually and push it into the vector.

Comment: You should **read the documentation** for [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: There is no form of `std::getline` that accepts two stream objects.

Comment: If I cant use `std::getline` then what can I use to replace it's functionality in this situation?

Comment: @Joe -- nobody said you can't use `std::getline`. Read the documentation. And you might want to dig out the documentation for `std::stringstream` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `std::getline()` to read from a `std::ifstream` *directly* into a `std::stringstream`.  You can only read into a `std::string`, which you can then assign to the `std::stringstream`, eg:

```cpp
vector<int> gameScore;
vector<string> playerName;
string name, line;
int score;

while (getline(in, line)){
    istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> name;
    playerName.push_back(name);
    cout << name << " ";

    while (iss >> score){
        gameScore.push_back(score);
        cout << score << " ";
    }
}
```